# Installation failed: Could not copy file. elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/migration/mapping.js

Tags: wordpress, elementor

This happens when I try to install Elementor online directly from the WordPress plugin store

**Installation failed: Could not copy file. elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/migration/mapping.js**

and when I try to install it via FTP it shows this Error message

**Failed to write file to disk.**

I tried deactivating all other plugins and when i tried again a new error appeared
**Installation failed: Could not copy file. elementor/core/settings/general/manager.php**

Anyone with an idea why this is happening?

Comment: I found a solution , I installed an old version of Elemntor and updated it the version I used is 2.5.0 you can download it at the official website of elemntor in WordPress, make sure to delete elemntor from your WordPress before reinstalling it